# Nested css counters with leading zeros

Tags: css, css-content

Is it possible to combine the css `counters()` function with leading zeros, producing a list such as this:

```
Item 01
  Item 01.01
  Item 01.02
    Item 01.02.01
```

Leading zeros are possible using `content: counter(name, decimal-leading-zero)`, and combining nested counters is possible using `content: counters(name, ".")`.

I know of workarounds if the level of nesting is known (i.e. I know the list will only ever nest 3 levels deep), but does anyone know if it's possible to combine these for lists of an unknown level of nesting?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you can combine these — just supply the counter style as the last argument to `counters()`:

```
content: counters(name, ".", decimal-leading-zero)
```

Comment: That's great, I had been staring at the spec for a while and just couldn't see it, thanks! Edit [found it now](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#counter).

Comment: Could one control the number of leading zeros or total number of digits? Similar to `fprintf()`?

Comment: @Royi: I don't think you can with just counters() but maybe a custom counter style can.